# if-else statement in python with django

Tags: python, django

I am quite new to django/python.
I am trying to create a field that outputs a value depending on the value of another field. I have looked all over the internet but can't find anything to help me.

I have a python condition:

```
def _final(obj):  
    if obj.final > '40,000':  
        return obj.match_score == 1  
    elif obj.final >= '35,000' and obj.final <= '40,000':  
        return obj.match_score == 2  
    elif obj.final >= '30,000' and obj.final <= '35,000':  
        return obj.match_score == 3  
    else:  
        return None
```

This is how I've defined the 2 fields in django models:

```
match_score = Derived(NumberField(null=True, default=None), _final)  
final = NumberField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
```

It runs but when I enter a number for "final", it doesn't output anything in "match_score"

Thanks for your help.

Editing the formatting of code and indentation

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct formatting for the last line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem:

```
def _final(obj):  
if obj.final > 40000:  
    return 1  
elif obj.final >= 35000 and obj.final <= 40000:  
    return 2  
elif obj.final >= 30000 and obj.final <= 35000:  
    return 3  
else:  
    return 0
```

The two fields remained defined in the same way. Thanks for your contribution guys!

Answer (score 5):

You need to *set* the values, not return booleans

```
def _final(obj):  
   if obj.final > '40,000':  
       obj.match_score = 1  
   elif obj.final >= '35,000' and obj.final <= '40,000':  
       obj.match_score = 2  
   elif obj.final >= '30,000' and obj.final <= '35,000':  
       obj.match_score = 3
```

Also, it looks fishy to me that you compare with strings ('40,000') instead of numbers (40000 - no quotes, no comma)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Nothing still shows up on the field though. I have also tried taking off the quotes and commas, no change still.

Comment: Try adding print-statements to verify if code is called. I am not familiar with Django ORM, but maybe saving is needed.

Comment: Thanks for you help... I found a way around i. I'll post the answer now

Answer (score 0):

Being that `match_score` is computed would this be better suited as a method on the model instead of a field?

### models.py

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    final = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def match_score(self):  
        if self.final > 40000:  
            return 1  
        elif self.final >= 35000 and self.final <= 40000:  
            return 2  
        elif self.final >= 30000 and self.final <= 35000:  
            return 3
```

### template

```
{{ obj.match_score }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help... I found a way around it and have posted my answer